# Event listing, filtering events with search

Tags: search, faceted-search

I'm working on UI for an event listing website. I have a dilemma. I want to include filters, without making the user think they have to use the search bar.

I curently have something like this

1. Event listing when search is not being used:
   [image]
2. Event listing when search is being used
   [image]

**Anyways, the problem is this:**

When the user visits the site - the **"Today**" filter is set as default. There is no "**All events**" filter button available to the user (too many events to list).

However, when the user uses search - the "All events" filter appears and becomes active.

My logic is - if the user uses search - he is most likely interested in all the instances of the keyword (let's say the user searches for a band - he most likely wants to know WHEN are they playing and less likely to answer if they are playing "today").

1. The problem is, would the user get confused because of the sudden apperiance of the "All events filter".
2. The second problem is: if the user is interested in "this month". So he changes from "all events" to "this month", and then wants to search for something else - should the search jump again on "all events" or stay on "this month".

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to search engine, it really makes sense to display all results.

**For team Search - "Queen"**

When a user is looking for a specific team, they may be interested in events in the past (remembrance) or future (taking part), so applying filters is good idea to clarify the result.

Question. Should filters be remembered or reset when a new search is made?

It's difficult for me to decide when, for example, we're looking for events this week (diffraction can be repeated filter all the time)

The action can be helpful - reset filters (?)

Whereas the **all events** button, I think, should be the default one.
(without having to select it - programmatically defined in the constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Show All Events by default (current and future, not past) starting with the very next event that matches the criteria. You want to make it easy for a user holding their phone, looking up information about an event that's imminent, as well as users who are looking for a future event.

Users can then use filters to narrow down their options.

Answer (score 0):

1. If All Events button is placed, it'll confused the user because the meaning of "All Events" seemed ambiguous - i.e. are you referring to all events for the search word across the entirety of time or are you referring to all events that are listed on the website without any filters? In addition, I noticed there is reset filters link below the search bar, and that seems to intuitively overlap with All Events. What I suggest is not to put in All Events button and leave the reset filters alone to do the work. The search results should display all event across the entirety of time by default.
2. If the user has set the events to this month and subsequently searches with another keyword, you should search with "this month" filter activated. However, please put on filter applied feedback on the "this month" button so that users know the filter is being activated can he can deactivate it if not needed. When the "this month" filter is deactivated, then all events across the entirety of time should be displayed.